# Cannot find boost include directories when add boost via FetchContent

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to add boost library to my project via FetchContent.

In my CmakeLists.txt i wrote:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    boost
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
    GIT_TAG        master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

But when i'm trying to include something from boost i'm getting error.
Include example:

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
```

Error:

```
C:/rep/OrderBook/src/orders/Order.h:14:10: fatal error: boost/container/flat_set.hpp: No such 
file or directory
   14 | #include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: No, i didn't find way to fix fetchcontent, so i used find_package.

Comment: here is what I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73933840/2685239